# Why "checked" does not make the Toggle buttons checked by default?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a set of toggle buttons in a custom form using the following lines:

```
    <div class="calc-toggle-wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" :checked="element.isChecked" :value="element.value" @change="change(event, element.label)" />
        <label></label>
    </div>
```

I want to make all these toggle buttons "on" or "checked" by default. I added the following to the end of the input () tag but nothing worked:

1. checked
2. checked="checked"
3. checked="true"

The toggle buttons on my form are still unchecked by default. I am not sure why it is not working or what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property to set the default value of the checkbox. For example:

```
computed: {
  isChecked: {
    get() {
      return this.element.isChecked;
    },
    set(value) {
      this.element.isChecked = value;
      // Add the value to the form here
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, you can bind the checkbox to the isChecked value using the v-model directive:

```
<div class="calc-toggle-wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isChecked" :value="element.value" @change="change(event, element.label)" />
  <label></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is part of a custom form developed with a plugin. I do not have the ability to modify Javascript here. I tried to modify the toggle (checkbox) element through HTML but I was not able to do this. Would you know how else I could accomplish this?

Comment: :checked="element.isChecked" is jquery selector. When I remove it, and add "checked" the toggle buttons do become checked by default, but then the values of the toggle do not get added to the form (this is a cost simulator, allowing users to add or remove addon services with toggle buttons to see how much a service will ultimately cost). Thanks.

Comment: Alright, Anna. I will just edit the answer above.